# How to change routes in backbone app , with change of event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone js application
I have some filters on a view. Is there any way to change route once I change filters on view

Comment: What do you mean change route?

Comment: When I change filters I want the filters to be part of the url , so the backbone can automatically handle the hashchange, I dont have to re-render the view

Answer (score 2):

You can call "saveLocation" in your controller with the hash location you want to save. This will add an entry in the history for that location.

You can also do window.location.hash = "xxx" but saveLocation is how backbone was designed.

Comment: how do i get the instance of the controller in a view?

Comment: In our stuff, we really minimize what we do in views; favoring instead to defer to a controller.  So we would have the view trigger an event to a controller.  At that point, the controller then would have access to the saveLocation method.  On a different note, I wasn't sure if your view was reacting to the filter.  If so, a controller might do that by using the above-mentioned event and modifying the underlying model or collection.  Then the view could be bound to the change event and refresh itself.

Comment: @Bill, How do u create model for a view, if your view needs to be created using data from different DB collection ( I m using MongoDB) ?

Comment: You create a model possibly with results returned from your server where the model has attributes and possibly associations.  You pass a model into a view upon creation.

Comment: @Bill is there any way to pass the filter parameters to collection?

Comment: @Bill , used the following approach and seems this is wht I was looking for 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946057/backbone-js-collection-get-vars

Comment: Which answer did you use off of that question?  Consider giving it an upvote since all answers sit at zero.  That might help someone else who is not sure which approach to use.  Glad to be of help.